# How add autoincrement to existing table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, auto-increment

Is there any ways to add autoincrement to primary key in already existing table in Oracle 12c. May be with ALTER TABLE function or smth, I mean without triggers and sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can **not** "modify" existing primary key column into a "real" identity column.

If you want to do that, you'll have to drop the current primary key column and then alter table and add a new *identity* column.

---

Workaround is to use a sequence (or a trigger), but - you said you don't want to do that. Anyway, if you decide to use it:

```
SQL> create table test
  2   (id   number constraint pk_test primary key,
  3    name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, 'LF');

1 row created.

SQL> create sequence seq_test start with 2;

Sequence created.

SQL> alter table test modify id default seq_test.nextval;

Table altered.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('BF');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 LF
         2 BF

SQL>
```

Or, with dropping current primary key column (note that it won't work easy if there are foreign keys involved):

```
SQL> alter table test drop column id;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test add id number generated always as identity;

Table altered.

SQL> select * From test;

NAME               ID
---------- ----------
LF                  1
BF                  2

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('test');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

NAME               ID
---------- ----------
LF                  1
BF                  2
test                3

SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome, @Tarik.